# Access Query Average Numbers by Row

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that contains different project, the people who work on it, and their grade level.

I'm trying to write an access query that will give an average grade level based on project.

[image]

But I can't figure out how to get the average grade level.
It would be something like table below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no intrinsic function for aggregating fields of record. To average, would have to add the fields and divide by number of data elements: `(field1 + field2 + field3 + field4 + field5)/5`. Complication introduced because not all fields have data so denominator is not static. A VBA custom function could handle this.

```
Function RAvg(ParamArray FieldValues()) As Variant
'----------------------------------------------------
' Function RAvg() averages all numeric arguments passed to it.
' If none of the arguments are numeric, it returns null.
'-----------------------------------------------------
Dim dblTotal As Double
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim varArg As Variant
For Each varArg In FieldValues
   If IsNumeric(varArg) Then
      dblTotal = dblTotal + varArg
      lngCount = lngCount + 1
   End If
Next
If lngCount > 0 Then
   RAvg = dblTotal / lngCount
Else
   RAvg = Null
End If
End Function
```

Call function from query:

`SELECT Project, RAvg([Stage 1 Grade], [Stage 2 Grade], [Stage 3 Grade], [Stage 4 Grade], [Stage 5 Grade]) AS AvgGrade FROM Projects;`

Alternative would be to normalize data structure then build an aggregate query. A UNION query can rearrange fields to normalized data structure. UNION will not allow duplicate records. Use UNION ALL to pull all data, even if it duplicates. There is no query designer or wizard for UNION, must type in SQLView of query builder.

```
SELECT Project, [Stage 1 person] AS Person, [Stage 1 grade] AS Grade, "S1" AS Stage FROM Projects
UNION ALL SELECT Project, [Stage 2 person], [Stage 2 grade], "S2" FROM Projects
UNION ALL SELECT Project, [Stage 3 person], [Stage 3 grade], "S3" FROM Projects
UNION ALL SELECT Project, [Stage 4 person], [Stage 4 grade], "S4" FROM Projects
UNION ALL SELECT Project, [Stage 5 person], [Stage 5 grade], "S5" FROM Projects;
```

Now use that query as source for an aggregate (GROUP BY) query that uses Avg() function.